# How to handle oauth 2.0 refresh tokens via angularjs 1.x

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0

Hi I was wondering how people nowadays handle oauth 2.0 refresh tokens?
I've seen an example on how people typically create a buffer queue for all the rejected async requests due to the bearer token being expired. Then just handle it through an http interceptor mixed in with some event emissions, etc etc.

It seems very convoluted to me and was wondering if there are any other angular (1.x) implementations that exist that handle this flow.